# Is it possible to restore only the schema and stored procedures from a MS SQL database backup?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have a full MS SQL Backup file that I would like to extract the stored procedures and schema from. Is there a way to restore **only** the schema definitions and stored procedures without restoring the data/table rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, but you could restore it to a temporary database and then script it all from there.

Answer (score 0):

What SQL Server version (and tools) are you using? Under SQL 2000, I remember the "Import/Export Data" wizard, that let you specify which objects you wanted to import and where. You could even perform queries to obtain a subset of data.

Comment: I'm using SQL2005 and SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible in SQL Server 2012. Right click your database -> tasks -> generate scritps ...

Here all options are available.

Comment: I see that, SQL Server has been able to do that for quite a few versions now. I don't think that this answer will solve the original question though.