# SQL Server restore and backup per schema

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-schema, database-backups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2005 restore one schema only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929327/sql-server-2005-restore-one-schema-only)

I have a database that contains several schemas in SQL Server 2008 R2. All schemas contain the same tables. Now I want to be able to restore a backup of only one schema, while leaving the other schemas the way they are.

I'm looking for something equivalent to using `pg_restore --schema="schemaname"` in PostgreSQL. Is there any way I can do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Already asked twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427526/is-it-possible-to-restore-only-the-schema-and-stored-procedures-from-a-ms-sql-dat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929327/sql-server-2005-restore-one-schema-only

Answer (score 6):

MSSQL doesnt have a posibility to backup/restore only 1 schema.
You can still perform partial backup of a database by grouping tables of one schema to a specific filegroup and make a filegroup backup.