# Schema Migration

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with small Spring MVC application(Spring, Hibernate, JPA, SQL Server). Sometimes I need to make changes to Entity and Schema in Database is also changed accordingly.

I want to know if there is some way to generate script that will update my database schema to new one - without destroying my data because I want to use it production environment.

Comment: Flyway, Liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQL Server but i'm sure that there are a way to restore and backup your schema, i google it and i find some links like this :

**About database**

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35288/sql-server-backup-restore-schema-only

http://sqlsoldier.net/wp/sqlserver/schemaonlybackupsandrestores

[Is it possible to restore only the schema and stored procedures from a MS SQL database backup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427526/is-it-possible-to-restore-only-the-schema-and-stored-procedures-from-a-ms-sql-da)

[SQL Server 2005 restore one schema only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929327/sql-server-2005-restore-one-schema-only)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190190.aspx

**About the your code**

We generaly use some STATIC variable like the name of schema and the name of database, so when we try to make some changes like your case it will be easy to change it for example:

In **Enties** we use this way :

Ordinary way

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "antecedent", schema = "sch_medecin")
```

With Static variables way

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "antecedent", schema = static_class.SCHEMA_NAME)
```

Hope you get my point and hope this can help you.